# git undo alias with xargs

Tags: git, alias, xargs

I have a git alias (`git undo`) that undoes everything in the working directory, including new files, changed files, and deleted files:

```
!git reset --hard && git ls-files -d | xargs -0 git rm --ignore-unmatch && git clean -fq
```

On OS X, this works great.  On Linux, however, I run into the following issue: if no files have been deleted from the repository, the `git ls-files -d | xargs -0 git rm --ignore-unmatch` command will fail (`xargs` will be passed nothing).

Is there a way to have `xargs` silently move on if it receives nothing from `git ls-files`?

Comment: If you're passing the `-0` option to `xargs` then it's important that you also use the `-z` option with `git ls-files`.

Comment: Note that to undo *everything*, you may (or may not) want to say `git clean -qfdx` (see `git help clean`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a `git reset --hard` before it, the `git ls-files -d` should never generate any output (and if it did, you would want to use `git ls-files -d -z` to have it produce NUL-terminated output for `xargs -0`).

Once you have done `git reset --hard`, the tracked portion of the working tree and the whole index will match the HEAD commit. `git ls-files -d` will only show files that are in the index but not in the working tree. Since the working tree will have everthing that the index has, there should never be any deleted files after a hard reset.

The `git clean` bit is useful to delete untracked files (which `git reset --hard` will not touch), but you might want to change it to `git clean -dfq` to also delete wholly untracked directories).

Comment: Ahhh, okay - I see.  Trying to do too much at once, it seems.

Answer (score 2):

From the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs):

> --no-run-if-empty, -r
>   If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run
>   the command.  Normally, the command is run once even if there is
>   no input.  This option is a GNU extension.

Make sure your version of xargs has that option (`man xargs`)

Comment: That looks like the answer - strange that the OS X version of xargs doesn't have this option (or uses it by default).  Guess I'll have to make some OS-specific aliases. ;)

Comment: OS X is FreeBSD based, and so has the FreeBSD version of xargs. It's POSIX compliant, but does not have GNU extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use xargs' "-r" option:

```
xargs -r -0 git rm --ignore-unmatch
```

That way, if `ls-files` shows nothing, xargs won't call `git rm` at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is "git clean" (man git-clean): Remove untracked files from the working tree